# AWS RDS IOPS v Aurora IOPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I am planning to migrate my current AWS RDS PostgreSQL database to AWS Aurore PostgreSQL. Currently, RDS uses GP3, whose default baseline is 3000 IOPS. From the information I've read on the AWS website, Aurora does not use EBS, but a shared network storage that forms a cluster. The size scales automatically.

When trying to price AWS Aurora, one factor is the Baseline IO rate (per second). I suspect that this is not the same as IOPS from RDS, because entering a value of 3000 there very significantly affects the final valuation.

May I ask someone with experience how to relate IOPS from RDS to Aurora?

Answer (score 0):

With Aurora, you pay a certain rate (which varies depending on the AWS Region) per million I/O operations. So you would estimate how many IOPS you really experience and plug that into the pricing calculator. I presume the 3000 IOPS from RDS was the maximum you could ever need during the busiest peak, not the amount that was really happening 24x7x365.

You can see here the network bandwidth limits for Aurora depending on the instance class:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html#Concepts.DBInstanceClass.Summary

I am a big fan of the recently announced I/O-optimized configuration:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/05/amazon-aurora-i-o-optimized/

It bakes the price of the I/O into the charges for instance hours and storage, which are easier to predict. So it's cheaper for a busy cluster that otherwise would have lots of I/O charges, although not as good a deal for a relatively lightly used cluster. (But you can switch from I/O-optimized back to the traditional I/O billing with no downtime.)